# Javascript accordion - collapse all

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have created a javascript accordion, which works when one accordion is always open, I was wondering how I might modify my code so that the accordion, can also be closed when clicked again - so that all are collapsed?

```
    $('.accordion-bottom').hide();

    $('.accordion-link').on('click', global.toggleAccordian);

    };

    global.toggleAccordian = function(e){
        var $Arrow = $(this).find('.arrow');
        var $parentDiv = $(this).parent();
        var $bottomAccordion = $parentDiv.siblings('.accordion-bottom');
        var $accordionLi = $parentDiv.parents().eq('1');

        var $siblingLis = $accordionLi.siblings('li');
        var $siblingBotAccordions = $siblingLis.find('.accordion-bottom');
        var $siblingArrows = $siblingLis.find('.arrow');


     $siblingArrows.addClass('arrow-down');

    if (!$accordionLi.hasClass('active')){
        $bottomAccordion.slideDown('slow');
        $Arrow.removeClass('arrow-down');
        $siblingBotAccordions.stop().slideUp('slow');
    }


    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="accordion">
        <li>
           <div class="item-inner-padding accordion-item">
               <div class="accordion-top">
            <a href="#" class="accordion-link">Title<span class="arrow arrow-down">Down</span></a>

               </div>
            <div class="accordion-bottom">

            </div>
            </div>
       </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: post your HTML as well please.

Comment: use `.slideToggle()` on whatever you want to slide up/down, and then use `.siblings()` to close the rest

Comment: any reason you're not using http://jqueryui.com/accordion/?

Comment: I wanted to do it without the jquery ui accordion to have more control and see how it was done.

Comment: added markup. @ashley can you give me an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FKAAM/2/. is this what you mean?

Comment: It seems to break when I use my markup, any ideas why? http://jsfiddle.net/FKAAM/8/